# false onItemClick on Scrolling a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView (With a custom adapter). It is workin fine but a small problem.
When I try to scroll the listview the row where I touch to begin srolling gets unchecked. (It was checked earlier by clicking on the row) (A click on the row check the checkbox in the onItemClick event of the listview).

So Whenever I try to scroll if the row item is selected it gets deselected. :(

Dont know how to fix it

Comment: You'll need to maintain a list of items that you checked and manually check/uncheck them while you're scrolling and binding your views. ListViews won't maintain that checked state for you

Comment: I am maintaining that. The problem is that the code is not able to diffrentiate that the OnItemClick event from a single click or from a scroll. The moment I try to scroll the listview I get an onItemClick

Comment: Why aren't you using onListItemClick like you should be?

Comment: What I meant to say is that the OnItemClick is called the moment I touch the phone screen to begin scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a boolean array to keep position where checked (true) and unchecked (false).
When an item is checked, update its state following its position and also call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to validate listview by new dataset.